# Sublime tab snippet in xml string

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have created a snippet that is tab triggered by the string

```
\n
```

and it inserts

```
&#10;
```

When i dod this in xml the tab trigger fails and places \name instead, unless I do it outside of any xml node.

How can I have this tab trigger take priority over any other completion?

Answer (score 0):

## Example

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
&#10;
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>\n</tabTrigger>
    <scope>embedding.php</scope>
    <description>PHP</description>
</snippet>
```

[Sublime Text Snippets Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Comment: I don't completely understand this answer.

Comment: Show the complete snippet you're trying to create. You probably need to narrow the scope more.

Comment: I don't see how narrowing the scope would change anything since it would just be a subset of the previous scope....

Comment: Show the full snippet and I'll have a better idea of what it is that you're trying to do. I obviously  misunderstand what you want.

Comment: @ScottF btw A more specific scope will prioritise the snippet over other snippets that have less specific scopes, which from your question "How can I have this tab trigger take priority over any other completion?" may be what you want.